# Knockout Js: values for table row duplicates in IE9

Tags: knockout.js

For example if i have table with column "ID", values under ID will be repeated twice in every row. This issue exists only in Ie9. Please suggest what can be the possible solution for this.
My Html markup is as follows.

```
     <script>
        var viewModels;
        requirejs(
            ["vm.attendanceMarking", "vm.bookcab"],
            function (vmattendanceMarking, vmbookcab) {

                viewModels = {
                    vmattendanceMarking: vmattendanceMarking,
                    vmbookcab: vmbookcab

                };
               vmattendanceMarking.VMobsCabDetails();
               viewModels.vmattendanceMarking.VMinit();
               viewModels.vmbookcab.VMGetCabRequestData();

                $(document).ready(function () {

                    ko.applyBindings(viewModels);
                });
            });


    </script>

       <tbody>
                        <!-- ko foreach: AttendanceList -->
                        <tr id='myrows' data-bind="attr: { id: 'row-' + tripId }">

                            <td>
                                <div style="display:inline-block">
                                    <label data-bind="text: EmployeeId" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div style="display:inline-block">
                                    <label data-bind="text: slot" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div style="display:inline-block">
                                    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsPresent">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div style="display:inline-block">
                                    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsChecked">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- /ko-->
                    </tbody>
```

Markup of table after generation in IE9:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
  <label data-bind="text: EmployeeId" />
Bangalore 
  <label data-bind="text: EmployeeId" />
Bangalore
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _values under ID will be repeated twice_? Could you please reduce the code in your question to the problematic parts, and also include the generated, problematic markup, once how it should be and once how it is generated in IE9?

Comment: Thanks janfoeh for your quick reply. I have added the markup post generation in IE9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup is invalid, which can lead to unpredictable results.

[`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) elements are not allowed to be self-closing. Use `<label></label>` instead.

Comment: @user1694105 Great to hear! Could you please accept this answer by clicking on the check mark on the left? This way, your question does not show up as 'unanswered' anymore. PS — welcome to Stack Overflow!